# Service Injection Error on Liferay Portlet

Tags: angularjs, liferay, portlet

I have develop a Liferay portlet and using AngularJS for the slient side. By using service injection such as **$scope** in controller will produce an error of the following:-

> Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

Example code:-

```
<script>
function PayrollCalcCtrl($scope){
}
</script>
```

If **$scope** is removed, no error will occur. Any workaround to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS optimizer/obfuscator is messing with your dependencies.
Take a look at the [DI docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

You'll want to define your controller in $inject or inline annotation:

```
var MyController = function(myScope) {
  ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

or

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  ...;
}]);
```

Comment: Is this the right way to declare the app object ? app= angular.module('myApp', []);

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Just add `var ` in front. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, every in perfect order now.